# Create a rectangle to cover a rotated Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

If I have a Rectangle class in C# how can I get a rectangle which encompasses it when it's rotated?

Basically I want to find the rectangle for a rotated rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious how do you keep your Rectangle as a data structure, I mean, a rectangle is 2D and XNA makes me think about 3D.

However, even in 2D and 3D, i think what you want is called AABB (axis aligned bounding box), which is very easy to find because it is defined by the two points formed by the minimums and, respective, maximums on each axis of each point of the original rectangle transformed with your rotation.

LATER EDIT:

For a Rectangle structure that contains X, Y, Width and Height, the rectangle has this two points:

```
(x1, y1) = (X, Y) and 
(x2, y2) = (X + Width, Y + Width).
```

When you rotate the rectangle, you practically rotate this two points and obtain:

```
(xr1, yr1) = rotate(x1, y1)
(xr2, yr2) = rotate(x2, y2).
```

Now, the rectangle you want is defined by the points of these coordinates:

```
p1 = new Point(Min(xr1, xr2), Min(yr1, yr2))
p2 = new Point(Max(xr1, xr2), Max(yr1, yr2))
```

rotate is the method that rotates your rectangle by an angle around a certain point.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the necessary calculations for a Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Rectangle structure.

Comment: I don't understand this: (xr1, yr1) = rotate(x1, y1) How is x1, y1 being rotated?

Comment: You have to look at all 4 points, not just the top left and bottom right.  Think of rotating the rectangle 45 degrees.  The X or Y of those two points will be equal but the other points will stick out to the sides.

Comment: @Jason - you're right, i missed that, i was thinking of an optimization and optimized too much. So indeed, all four points should be taken into consideration.

Comment: @meds - (xr1, yr1) = rotate(x1, y1) means that xr1 and yr1 are the coordinates of the point (x1, y1) rotated the way you rotate the rectangle (with a certain angle, around a certain point).

Answer (score 0):

How are you rotating the rectangle to start with?  to get the bounding box you need to look at the four resulting points and find the min and max for Y and X,

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should open another question then since I actually meant to ask this as 'how do I rotate a rectangle', I just assumed getting a rotated rectangles AABB would involve the actual rotation calculations (for some reason).